# How can "$y = \sqrt{-x}$ " be sketched on the x-y plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

I was reading James Stewart's book Calculus 5th edition (international student edition) and I came across an example that seemed wrong to me. In chapter 1 section 3, he talks about transformations of functions (i.e., vertical and horizontal shifts, vertical and horizontal stretching and reflecting).

In example 1, the function $y=\sqrt{x}$ is provided and it is asked to graph its transformation $y=\sqrt{-x}$. The solution is provided as below.

My question is, shouldn't such a function be in the realm of imaginary/complex numbers? If so, then how is it graphed on the x-y plane?

[image]

Comment: When $x\le 0$, then $-x\ge 0$

Comment: If $x$ is negative then $-x$ is positive.

Comment: In this case if $x>0$ then $y$ is imaginary and if $x<0$ then $y=\sqrt{\left|x\right|}$ .  That's why the plot for y is reflected across the y-axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you see "$-x$" as a negative number? That's understandable, given the negative sign. But $-x$ *can* be positive, when $x$ itself is negative. And then $\sqrt{-x}$ is something that is real, like $\sqrt{-(-4)}=2$. And that is why the graph of $y=\sqrt{-x}$ is only appearing on the left side of the coordinate plain, where $x$ is negative.

Answer (score 3):

Not if x < 0, user. Notice carefully that the domain of f(x) lies to the left of the positive y axis, meaning that x < 0. Since x< 0, -x> 0 and the square root is perfectly valid. In fact,you can think of f as taking the square root of the absolute value of negative reals. Now if $x \geq 0$, you'd be completely correct.

Of course, the important question in that case is-what does it mean to graph a complex valued function? Turns out this isn't as easy to answer as it looks at first: Since f: **C** $\rightarrow$ **C** is a function of 2 variables i.e. z = x+ iy for every z$\in$ **C** , the graph of such a map lies in a four dimensional space. So how to do you graph such mappings?

An interesting question for your first week of complex variables.............